# Entity Framework Code First: Many to Many relationships. More complex than usual scenario

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, many-to-many

Hi Everybody and thanks for taking the time to read my question.

I have the following 3 POCOs: Menu, ApplicationRole and Action.

Each of these POCO has 2 properties Id and Description.

Menu has a many-to-many relationship with ApplicationRole and a many-to-many relationship with Action, defined as follows:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Menu>().HasMany(t => t.Roles).WithMany(p => p.Menus).Map(m => { m.MapLeftKey("MenuId"); m.MapRightKey("RoleId"); m.ToTable("MenuRoles"); }); 

modelBuilder.Entity<Menu>().HasMany(t => t.Actions).WithMany(p => p.Menus).Map(m => { m.MapLeftKey("MenuId"); m.MapRightKey("ActionId"); m.ToTable("MenuActions"); });
```

So far pretty much standard. Now, I need to create a permission table to map menus, roles and actions together. I can easily do so by creating an entity permission as follows:

```
public class Permission
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0), DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public Guid MenuId { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 1), DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public Guid ActionId { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 2), DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public string RoleId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("MenuId")]
    public virtual Menu Menu { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ActionId")]
    public virtual Action Action { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("RoleId")]
    public virtual ApplicationRole Role { get; set; }
}
```

However, doing so will create the foreign keys with the individual POCO entities and not with the associations MenuActions and MenuRoles. Is there a way to create such relationships without having to explicitly create MenuActions and MenuRoles entities.

I am OK with both fluent API or annotations, but would prefer a solution based on annotations if possible.

Thanks in advance for your help !